# Template template substitution in function

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing my own `UniquePtr` and I would like to test that it has the same interface as the `std::unique_ptr`. So I wrote a function:

```
class A
{
  A() { }
  ~A() { }
};

class B
{
  B() { }
  ~B() { }
};


template <template <typename Type> class UPtr>
void test_unique_ptr_interface()
{
  UPtr<A> p1(new A);
  {
    UPtr<A> p2(std::move(p1));
    p1 = std::move(p2);
  }

  UPtr<B> p1(new B);
  {
    UPtr<B> p2(std::move(p1));
    p1 = std::move(p2);
  }
  ...
}
```

And then I would like to call it like this:

```
test_unique_ptr_interface<std::unique_ptr>(); 
test_unique_ptr_interface<UniquePtr>();
```

The first call tests that the `std::unique_ptr` passes the tests, thus that I am testing the correct interface. The second call tests that my own `UniquePtr` implementation works as a drop in replacement. The function `test_unique_ptr_interface` will be a lot longer, I just posted a simple example.

However, I get an error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘test_unique_ptr_interface()’
   test_unique_ptr_interface<std::unique_ptr>();
```

How should I declare the `test_unique_ptr_interface()` function so that this compiles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look up the [declaration of `std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr):

```
template <class T, class Deleter = std::default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr;
```

It's a class template with 2 template parameters. To copy it exactly, you must change your class template to match, and change the test function:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class UPtr>
void test_unique_ptr_interface()
{
  // ...
}
```

An alternative would be to turn make the template template parameter variadic:

```
template <template <typename... > class UPtr>
void test_unique_ptr_interface()
{
  // ...
}
```

This would allow your class to keep just one template parameter. Note that it will then not be a full drop-in replacement for `std::unique_ptr`, though.

Comment: Thanks Angew! I didn't realize the Deleter must be present even if it has a default. I improved upon your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29659470/479532

Answer (score 3):

Change your template argument list to:

```
template<template<class...>class UPtr>
```

as `std::unique_ptr` takes 2 arguments, `template<class>class` won't match it.

How templates are matched in C++ is a bit strange (and I don't know the justification for it), but `template<class...>class` will match any `template class` that takes zero value-parameters (ie, only type parameters).

Both `std::unique_ptr<?>` (which takes 2 parameters, 1 of them defaulted) and `UniquePtr<?>` (which takes 1 parameter) will match.  Passing it one parameter will result in `std::unique_ptr` using its default second parameter.

It is annoying that a `template` that takes 2 parameters, the second defaulted, won't match `template<class>class`, but that is part of the "strange" way template template parameters are matched.  You could write an adapter:

```
template<class T>using unique_ptr1 = std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

and pass `unique_ptr1` directly to your `test_unique_ptr_interface`.

Alternatively:

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct unary_version {
  template<class T>
  using apply = Z<T>;
};
```

then

```
test_unique_ptr_interface< unary_version<std::unique_ptr>::template apply >
```

is another way without changing `test_unique_ptr_interface`.  But the right answer is to replace `test_unique_ptr_interface`.

Note that your lack of deleter means that you don't match the `unique_ptr` interface.  You could instead augment your class with those features.  You can rename your existing function to `test_unique_ptr_interface_with_one_arg`, and call it from `test_unique_ptr_interface` that also tests deleter functionality.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips! Indeed, I tested the `unique_ptr1` and it works. You are absolutely right, that I need to add a Deleter into my UniquePtr (it's on my TODO list). And the right way is to modify the template argument list.

Answer (score 1):

@Angew gave the correct answer, though with his specific suggestion I need to change `UPtr<A> p1(new A);` to `UPtr<A, std::default_delete<A>> p1(new A);`. To avoid this, I need to change the function declaration from

```
template <template <typename Type> class UPtr>
void test_unique_ptr_interface()
```

to

```
template <template <typename T, typename Deleter=std::default_delete<T>> class UPtr>
void test_unique_ptr_interface()
```

Then no further changes are necessary in the function body, I can still use `UPtr<A> p1(new A);` and everything compiles.

Answer (score 0):

`std::unique_ptr` takes *two* template parameters (type and deleter), so your template-template also needs to take those same two parameters.

Answer (score -3):

Use only (no need `template <typename Type>`)

```
template <class UPtr>
```

For test you can use std::is_base_of with static_assert
but i don't know how validate base template class

Comment: And how would that allow instantiating it with different types, as the OP does?

Comment: @angew Well, there is the missing `template<class A, class B> struct rebase; template<template<class...>class Z, class A, class B> struct rebase<Z<A>,B>{using type=Z<B>;}; template<class A, class B>using rebase_t=typename rebase<A,B>::type;` implied by the above interface.  Defter is just being succinct.

Comment: When using just "template <class UPtr>", I get "error: ‘UPtr’ is not a template".